# update URL as input value

Tags: php, laravel

I have a search box and when I enter the code in that search box it should show the required data on the web page. but I'm unable to fetch data by using the search box. because I am unable to send that code to my controller which is entered in the search box.
As well as when I am submitting the code in the search box the browser URL should replace that code (It is like an edit function)
So, can someone help me to get it done? The following code shows what I have done.

Thank You, everyone!

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Account\CodeController@codeResult', 'code'=> 'code'], 'method' => 'get' , 'class'=>"col12"]) !!}
        <div class="row mb-5">
            <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
                <div class="text-input-with-icon">
                    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback float-right"></span>
                    <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="barcode" placeholder="Search By code">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 mx-auto">
                <button type="submit" name="code" value="name" class="btn btn-reset">SEARCH
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: use ajax/axios for xhr request

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to send that code"? What actually happens?

Comment: code means what I search in the search box, data in the web page are automatically loaded in the initial load. it means I have given the code when initial load

Comment: Again... what actually happens? Have you done any debugging? Are you using any JS code to submit/validate the form? Do you get any errors? How are you handling the form after it's been submitted? We can give you better help if you explain the actual issue in more detail.

Comment: I have updated the question